# Getting variable from jq.exe output in Windows batch reading JSON

Tags: json, windows, batch-file, jq

I managed having a **JSON** file created by **ffprobe** which contains basic info about a video stream in a MKV container. By `jq-win64.exe "[.format.duration]" %%~ni.mkv.json` the duration of the movie is read correctly from the file and **jq** echos `["1:36:55.184000"]`. Now I want to store this value in a global variable of my script for further processing. I tried several approaches but each of them led to errors and/or left `%duration%` empty. I tried e.g.

```
   for %%i in (*.mkv) do (
      SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
      for /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN ('_tools\jq\jq-win64.exe "[.format.duration]" %%~ni.mkv.json') DO (SET duration=%%F)
      echo Duration is: %duration%
      ENDLOCAL
   )
```

but could not manage to echo `%duration%`. I think it can't be that hard, most likely I don't do the syntax right on Windows batch. Any ideas? Here is the JSON file as well:

```
{
    "format": {
        "filename": "TestFile_1080p_26Mbs_8bit_BT709.mkv",
        "nb_streams": 1,
        "nb_programs": 0,
        "format_name": "matroska,webm",
        "format_long_name": "Matroska / WebM",
        "start_time": "0:00:00.000000",
        "duration": "1:36:55.184000",
        "size": "17.586597 Gibyte",
        "bit_rate": "25.978148 Mbit/s",
        "probe_score": 100,
        "tags": {
            "title": "TestFile",
            "encoder": "libmakemkv v1.14.4 (1.3.5/1.4.7) win(x64-release)",
            "creation_time": "2019-08-17T21:01:18.000000Z"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without modifying your parenthesised command, possibly `@For /F "Delims=" %%F In ('_tools\jq\jq-win64.exe "[.format.duration]" %%~ni.mkv.json')Do @For /F "Tokens=*" %%G In ("%%A")Do @Set "duration=%%G"`. _I have no idea where `%%~ni` comes from, but if it's because your provided command is nested within another [tag:for-loop] you might need to enable delayed expansion, to use the variable named `duration` within the code block._

Comment: @Compo Yes, there is another for-loop and I already tried delayed expansion but it did not work, `%duration%` is empty. I extended my code example above.

Comment: If you're using delayed expansion, it would be `!duration!` if used inside the code block.

Comment: Okay, thanks, by using ```!duration!``` the variable is filled. But using your suggested cmdline above it just echos ```"Duration is: %A"``` and I can't figure out why. Using my cmdline from my example above it echos ```_tools\jq\jq-win64.exe "[.format.duration]" TestFile_1080p_26Mbs_8bit_BT709.mkv.json```, so I guess there's stg else wrong with the syntax.

Comment: Rome, it was a typo, I was supposed to use `%%F` not `%%A`. `@For /F "Delims=" %%F In ('_tools\jq\jq-win64.exe "[.format.duration]" "%%~ni.mkv.json" 2^>NUL')Do @For /F "Tokens=*" %%G In ("%%F")Do @Set "duration=%%G"`.

Comment: @Compo Okay, but now it echos ```Duration is: ]```. The closing bracket must come from jq and I guess it gives an array.

Comment: Well you probably don't need the extra level of expansion after all, `@For /F "Delims=" %%F In ('_tools\jq\jq-win64.exe "[.format.duration]" "%%~ni.mkv.json" 2^>NUL')Do @Set "duration=%%F"`. If this doesn't work we're going to need more actual output information.

Comment: No, this also only gives the bracket. The actual output of ```_tools\jq\jq-win64.exe "[.format.duration]" %%~ni.mkv.json``` is ```["1:36:55.184000"]``` while there are line breaks after the first and before the last bracket when jq echos to the cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) solution based upon my understanding after the comments:

```bat
    For /F Tokens^=2Delims^=^" %%F In (
        '_tools\jq\jq-win64.exe "[.format.duration]" "%%~ni.mkv.json" 2^>NUL')Do (
        Set "duration=%%F"
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        Echo( !duration!
        EndLocal
    )
```

Comment: This is working, thanks a lot. I don't know exactly why but I will figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the duration, then there's no need for intermediate JSONs, because FFprobe can also tell you that:

```
ffprobe.exe -v 0 -i <input> -show_entries format=duration -of compact=p=0:nk=1
1:36:55.184000
```

Create a variable:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN (
  'ffprobe.exe -v 0 -i <input> -show_entries format=duration -of compact=p=0:nk=1'
) DO SET duration=%%A
SET duration=1:36:55.184000
```

If you still want to parse FFprobe's JSON, then there's no need to create json-files either, as you can simply pipe it to JQ instead:

```
ffprobe.exe -v 0 -i <input> -show_format -of json | jq.exe -r .format.duration
1:36:55.184000
```

Create a variable:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN (
  'ffprobe.exe -v 0 -i <input> -show_format -of json ^| jq.exe -r .format.duration'
) DO SET duration=%%A
SET duration=1:36:55.184000
```